# How to call ModelCheckpoint (or any callback) explicitly in Keras?

Tags: machine-learning, callback, keras

My [ModelCheckpoint](https://keras.io/callbacks/) is intended to save model each epoch. Unfortunately, I don't use built-in epochs of [Model](https://keras.io/models/model/).

How to call ModelCheckpoint not via callback, but explicitly, when my code ends epoch, so that it does all it's job?

I found method `on_epoch_end`, but can't figure out, where to pass model itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each callback is derived from `Callback` abstract base class. It has `set_model` method which is used to pass the corresponding model. Check it in [callbacks.py](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/callbacks.py)